# buenas amigs estoy haciendo un reciclerview en un fragment y tengo un problema con este codigo

Tags: java, android-studio

buenas amigs estoy haciendo un reciclerview en un fragment y tengo un problema con el codigo no corre y los errores estan en estas lineas

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_projects, container, 
            false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerId);
            listapersonajes = new ArrayList<>();
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            //cargar la lista
            cargarlista();
            personajesadapter = new Personajesadapter(getContext(), 
            listapersonajes);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(personajesadapter);
    
    
             return view;
```

Comment: ¿Cúal es el error que aparece?...

Comment: No se entiende. Tienes que explicarte mejor. Que quieres decir con que "no corre"? Arroja una excepción al ejecutarse? No compila? Sabes como debuguear?